# Random object color via python

Tags: python, scripting

I do some testing for further learning python.

My setup is an Empty that spawns a cube every 60 tics on a random position. Now what I want is those cubes also get a random color. This is my code for it (attached to the cube on a seperate layer)

```
def objColor():  

    obstacle = scene.objects ["obstacle"]

    r = random.random()
    g = random.random()
    b = random.random()

    obstacle.color = (r,g,b,True)
```

What happens is that the first spawned cube gets a random color, but all others that follow don't. I assume that has something to do with blender changing the name of the following cubes to obstacle.001, 002 etc.

But how can I make sure that all the following cubes also get a random color?

Thanks for any help,
cheers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yep, you are assigning all new random colours to the first object.

```
def get_random_color():
    ''' generate rgb using a list comprehension '''
    r, g, b = [random.random() for i in range(3)]
    return r, g, b, 1
```

then in the loop, once you create the object you get a reference to it.
somethng like:

```
obj = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
obj.color = get_random_color()
```

This way you will call a function to get random rgba on every new object