# Low level fast way to create cube

Tags: scripting, performance

In the answer to this question it's said that the high level ops functions have low performance since they do a scene update:
[Python performance with Blender operators](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7358/python-performance-with-blender-operators)

I'm looking for a low level equivalent to this command, which creates a cube in the scene, with a given size and position:

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, enter_editmode=False, align="WORLD", location=(0,0,0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: That answer was written many years ago (2014) with a much earlier version of Blender. There have been a lot of changes since then to speed up and re-write the underlying code in Blender so it might not be an issue nowadays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one way to do it without having to depend on `bpy.ops`.

```
import bpy

name = "Cube"
size = 2
location = (0, 0, 0)
color = (0, 0, 1, 1)

# Generate the vertices and faces, edges are inferred from the polygons
s = size / 2
vertices = [(s, s, s),
            (s, s, -s),
            (s, -s, s),
            (s, -s, -s),
            (-s, s, s),
            (-s, s, -s),
            (-s, -s, s),
            (-s, -s, -s)]
faces = [(0, 2, 3, 1), (0, 1, 5, 4), (2, 0, 4, 6), (1, 3, 7, 5), (3, 2, 6, 7), (4, 5, 7, 6)]

# Create a new mesh and set generated data
mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
mesh.from_pydata(vertices, [], faces)

# Create a new material
material = bpy.data.materials.new(f"{name}Mat")

# Mark the material to use nodes and set the base color of the Principled shader and the display color
material.use_nodes = True
material.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'].default_value = color
material.diffuse_color = color

# Assign the material to the mesh
mesh.materials.append(material)

# Create a new object to hold the mesh and set its location
object = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
object.location = location

# Link the object to the active collection to be able to see it in the scene
bpy.context.collection.objects.link(object)
```

Running this 1000 times using a for loop takes about **0.0702** seconds on my PC. Running the first solution in X Y's answer takes about **0.0941** seconds. Running the second solution in X Y's answer takes about **0.2027** seconds. Running [the selected answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835134/in-python-how-do-i-generate-a-large-amount-of-cube-meshes-fast) for 1000 cubes takes about **0.0324** seconds. Tests were run in Blender 4.0.

---

**Edit 1:** If the mesh can be shared between the objects, the proposed answer can take around **0.0132** seconds to generate 1000 objects that use the same mesh data.

---

**Edit 2:** I added a few extra steps to create and assign a material to the generated mesh.

Comment: FYI, testing it too, X Y solution (the first one, without update functions) seems to be a bit faster than yours.

Comment: @lemon Did you undo after running each solution? Anyway, the fastest solution for me was the one linked to. I updated my answer.

Comment: I've created a function similar to X Y one (so with a loop on coords), but using your method. this way: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKhES.png

Comment: and yes, undo after each.

Comment: @lemon Do you mind passing me your results after you're done? I will update my post to include them. I don't know why our results do not agree.

Comment: here is my file: https://blend-exchange.com/b/Pnd018Lm/

Comment: @lemon It seems that you have a modified version of the first solution. Yes, that one runs faster on my PC too. It takes about **0.0456** seconds.

Comment: Yes, modified, because the functions named with "update" are not usefull here, just that.

Comment: @MrA I like your solution, I'm soon going to mark it as the answer. I'd also like to add a simple color to the recently created cubes. How can I do this? I usually do this by using the active object, similarly to this solution:
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/201874/how-to-add-a-color-to-a-generated-cube-within-a-python-script
(lemon's answer)

I want to have a separate material for each cube.

Comment: @BroDude Since we're creating the mesh, we can easily create a material and assign it directly. I gave the material a default blue color. Please note that I prepared the script to handle one cube only as the question was for one cube. If you want there to be a grid of cubes with different colors, sizes, and locations, we'll have to indent the code under one or more for loops and decide how to modify the code to satisfy our needs.

Comment: @MrA Thanks for relpying! I want to create a bunch of cubes with different colors. My current solution is too slow. I've created a new question regarding this: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305336/coloring-lots-of-cubes

Comment: You're welcome! I have to go now, but I've saved it to look at it as soon as I am available.

Answer (score 0):

Fast way to create 1000 same size cubes with different position

```
# tested in Blender 3.6
import bpy, bmesh, time

_temp = [None, None]

def N(context): pass

def update_disable():
    from bpy.ops import _BPyOpsSubModOp
    _temp[0] = _BPyOpsSubModOp
    _temp[1] = _BPyOpsSubModOp._view_layer_update
    _BPyOpsSubModOp._view_layer_update = N

def update_enable():
    _temp[0]._view_layer_update = _temp[1]

def add_cubes(coords, size=1):
    bm = bmesh.new()
    bmesh.ops.create_cube(bm, size=size)

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new('Cube')
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    mesh.update()
    bm.free()

    objects = bpy.data.objects
    objs = bpy.context.collection.objects

    for co in coords:
        ob = objects.new("Cube", mesh.copy())
        ob.location = co
        objs.link(ob)

    bpy.data.meshes.remove(mesh)


t = time.time()
update_disable() # Not required if no other ops are running
add_cubes([[r, r, r] for r in range (1000)])
# run other ops here..
update_enable()
bpy.context.view_layer.update()
print('run time: ', time.time() - t)
```

Other way

```
import bpy, time


t = time.time()

bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(size=1, enter_editmode=False, align="WORLD", location=(0,0,0), scale=(1, 1, 1))
cube = bpy.context.object

md = cube.modifiers.new('', 'ARRAY')
md.count = 1000
bpy.ops.object.modifier_apply(modifier=md.name)

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.separate(type="LOOSE")
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')

print('run time: ', time.time() - t)
```

Comment: I've tested it by curiosity. The update functions does not seem to change anything or more, it seems to be faster without them. Could you explain a bit what it is intend to do? Thanks

Comment: Do You mean the last 2 line: `bpy.context.view_layer.update()`? or `update_disable()`?

Comment: update_disable and _enable, yes

Comment: 0.11s with the three update functions and 0.06s without them 3, here.

Comment: Not required if no other ops are running, if there are lot of ops running, this method lot more faster, see the new update.

Comment: ok, that's for ops. Thanks

Comment: I've found a solution in the answer to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69835134/in-python-how-do-i-generate-a-large-amount-of-cube-meshes-fast

If I understand it correctly, it creates one cube with ops, then copies the object & mesh data with low level functions, then does a single update at the end.

Comment: Isn't disabling updating this way a bit of a hack? Can this solution break in future Blender versions?

Comment: No one knows because there are no developers here. Any content may change in future versions.